React Native Maps Showing Grey Background with Google Logo in CLI Project
I am working on a React Native project using React Native CLI and trying to display a Google Map using the react-native-maps package. However, the map only shows a grey background with the Google logo, and no map data is displayed.
Here's my setup:
App.js
import MapView, { Marker, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const markerCoordinate = {
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
  };

  const polylineCoordinates = [
    { latitude: 37.78825, longitude: -122.4324 },
    { latitude: 37.78885, longitude: -122.4325 },
    { latitude: 37.78925, longitude: -122.4326 },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.01,
          longitudeDelta: 0.01,
        }}
      >
        <Marker coordinate={markerCoordinate} title="My Marker" description="This is a marker description" />
        <Polyline coordinates={polylineCoordinates} strokeColor="#FF5733" strokeWidth={4} />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});

Key Configurations
Dependencies in package.json:
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.20.1"
}

AndroidManifest.xml:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <permission android:name="com.shop.shoppinglist.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.shop.addtask.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    
     <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
          android:value="my_api_key"/>
      </application>

In android/app/src/res/values/google_maps_api.xml: (Tried also without this file)
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">my_api_key</string>
</resources>

app/build.gradle: (Here, I tried different versions and without this dependency, same result)
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1")
}

Android Versions in build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "35.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 35
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"
    }
}

What I've Tried:

Verified the API key in the Google Cloud Console (ensured no restrictions and enabled the
Android Maps SDK).
Tested the same API key in an Expo project, which worked perfectly.
Searched various forums for solutions, but nothing worked.


did you checked out the solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69810638/3237884 ?
